# Bootstrap dialog blinking in chrome while working in Edge and Firefox

Tags: model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm using `bootstrap 4.0.0`. When I open any dialog box in my project its start blinking with back spots on the screen(As you can see the attached image).

I have search but didn't find any solution.

**Note**

My monitor is working fine. I have checked the same on other monitory as well but it behave the same with black spots.

[image: dialog]

[Bootstrap 4 link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)

Link Description: Above link is the Library which i'm using right now.